# PHP - Weird behaviour of mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

im running into a very strange problem all of a sudden:

I have a PHP script executing a query:

```
$query = "SELECT ShopOrderID, PaymentID FROM shop_order WHERE Done = 0 AND PaymentLockdate IS NOT NULL AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(OrderDate + 7200 < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())";
```

The query is fine, when I print it into pma it executes fine and gives me 12 results to be processed.

Now I do execute the query and gather the result:

```
$handle = new MySQLi(
    $config->getSqlHost(),
    $config->getSqlUser(),
    $config->getSqlPW(),
    $config->getSqlDbName(),
    $config->getSqlPort()
);

$result = $handle->query($query);
```

Now the add thing, if I try to loop the result:

```
if(is_object($result) == true) { //Is_object returns true!
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { //But this is an error o.O

    }
}
```

I get:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /var/www/(and so on...)/myscript.php on line 34
```

Now the weirdo thing is, if I do some tests on the object $result it says:

```
var_dump(is_object($result)); //bool(true) 

var_dump(get_class($result)); //string(13) "mysqli_result"

var_dump($handle->error()); //string(0) ""

var_dump($handle->errno()); //int(0)

var_dump($result); //object(mysqli_result)#4 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(2) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(13) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```

There is an absolutely valid result set with 13 rows and 2 fields according to my query. Perfectly fine and still when I try to loop it its a "non-object". What is happening here? Anyone encountered this problem?

Would appreciate any hints.

And no: The result is not overwritten anywhere, I did the var_dumps on the object 1 line before I call this: `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ...`

Comment: Stab in the dark: you're *overwriting* `$result` inside the loop...!?

Comment: Lolx!!, yes that was it, I was somewhat really tired when I wrote this yesterday and now I did not realize that. Thanks for fast help~

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm a little confused, PHP says $results is a non-object of the mysqli class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588828/im-a-little-confused-php-says-results-is-a-non-object-of-the-mysqli-class)